# How to combine data of multiple rows in one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with names of organisations and codes. Some organisations have multiple codes, some have only one code. I want to make a set that shows the organisation in one column, and all the codes of that organisation in another column.

This is how the dataset is right now:

[image]

And this is how it should be:

[image]

Does anyone know what script in Python I could use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df.astype({'code': str})
       .groupby('organisation', as_index=False)['code']
       .apply(', '.join))
```

```
print(out)

  organisation           code
0            A  100, 101, 102
1            B            103
2            C       104, 105
3            D            106
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby("organisation").code.apply(list)
```

Note that it produce a `pd.Series`. If you want to convert it in a `pd.DataFrame` use the `.to_frame()` method.